# Advantages and disadvantages of Encrypt HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

I am new to Web world. I am working in a project , which required encryption of HTML. I am doing encryption using following sites.

http://www.smartgb.com/free_encrypthtml.php
http://www.onlinehtmlencryption.com/

The project is build in dotnetnuke. The encryption is performed in JavaScript.

Can any body tell me its Advantages or Disadvantages ? so that i will be in better potion to decide.

Comment: There is never a "need" to generate "encrypted" HTML. Why do you think you "need" that?

Comment: I tried just `<html></html>` on the first site, and it had far more obfuscation than the second site, but the length of the code was much longer.

Comment: "I am working in a project , which required encryption of HTML" = when requirements are that out of whack, It's time to start looking for a new project. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Disadvantage: there's absolutely no point to it. The browser requires the raw HTML in order to be able to render the page. That means everything to *decrypt* the HTML must be given to it in the same turn. That makes this encryption pointless, as anyone can decrypt the HTML just the same as the browser must. You're not hiding anything from anyone, because you can't.

In fact, anyone can simply use the browser's DOM inspector (typically: right click > Inspect Element) to poke around the decrypted and rendered "HTML".

Advantage: Piss off yourself when working with your own site, if you're a masochist?

Comment: Especially given the *Inspect Element* almost everyone has in their context menu these days.

Comment: Actually, it's great if you wanna piss off anyone, including yourself, when you want to edit your html.

Comment: @Jack Added that, seems legit.

Comment: @JackCole but not that much, as it's trivial to open up firebug and look at the unencrypted source.

Comment: @DA I don't think it's trivial at all. "Oh, I need to change the class of this element. Let me just edit this file. What the...why doesn't CTRL+F find it? I guess I'll have to dig through the page code manually. Wait...what's all this obfuscated JS?"

Comment: Well, one would hope they're obfuscating as part of deployment--rather than manually in the source code. :)

Comment: Tell me one thing, by using SSL will the source code of an html page will appear in encrypted form at the client end??

Comment: @user No. You can never hide anything from the client! If the client isn't able to see it, there's no point in sending anything to him. SSL is for hiding the details of what is being sent from *3rd parties*. Your HTML "encryption" does not even do that.